Nested Accordion Controls are reporting as Null on Page_Load
I have a dropdownlist in a nested accordion.
On the page load I would like to bind that drop down list with data provided.  However, when the method tries to find the dropdownlist control, it cannot find it and treats it as a null entity. This breaks the page load.
Here is a sample of the code that I'm referring to:
        <Panes>
          <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID="apPane1" runat="server" Visible="true">
             <Header>
                <span class="AccordionLink">Header1</span>
             </Header>
             <Content>
                 <table style="width: 75%">
                    <tr>
                       <td style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px">
                           <asp:Panel ID="pnllandingpanel" runat="server"> 
                              <ajaxToolkit:Accordion ID="AccordionChartConfig" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" RequireOpenedPane="false" CssClass="accordian" HeaderCssClass="headerCssClass" FadeTransitions="true" TransitionDuration="500" AutoSize="None" ContentCssClass="contentCssClass" HeaderSelectedCssClass="headerSelectedCssClass">
                                  <Panes>
                                    <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID="apPanelLevel2" runat="server">
                                          <Header>
                                               <span class="AccordionLink">Link2</span>
                                          </Header>
                                          <Content>
                                             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLoadValue" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                          </Content>
                                          </Header>
                                   </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
                                 </Panes>
                          </td>
                       </tr>
                    </table>
              </Content>
        </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
</Accordion>

My c# code behind is simply:
ddlLoadValue = BindDDLValue(ddlLoadValue);

The code behind works.  I'm not worried about that.
If I don't need to load the dropdown list on page load, it works fine.  This happens when I am doing a new entry. However, when I try to load a saved entry, I need the controls in that nested accordion to populate.
I tried making sure the accordion was enabled and selected index was the one with the dropdown list.  I was expecting the program to find the control and populate the dropdown.

Try to do it after the page loads (Page LoadComplete) so the dropdown is available when it binds the data. It might help to understand the lifecycle events. Have a look at this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11235074/3785895

And how are you loading up these controls in a given pane? I see nothing that would stop or prevent you from running code that loads up some controls, including that of a some controls that includes a drop down list. I mean, even without the accordion, you have to load up those controls, load up the dropdown list of possible selections,  and THEN select/set the correct option in the ddl from the underlying data. This sounds like a issue even when not using a accordion at all.

The control was too buried for the page load to get to.  Somebody pointed me in the direction where I had to use findcontrol repeatedly to manually hone in on the proper control.  i.e. Dropdownlist btn1 = (Dropdownlist)Master.FindControl("apPanel").FindControl(...).FindControl("ddlLoadValue")

The solution was to manually navigate through the nest using FindControl.
    AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane optionspane = (AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane)Master.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("apPanel").FindControl("AccordionChartConfig").FindControl("apPanelLevel2");
    DropDownList dXAxisFormat = (DropDownList)optionspane.FindControl("ddlLoadValue");
       

I was able to render the page properly after doing this.

This had zero to do with a accordion control and everything to do with using and nesting the control inside of a table which means you can have multiple instances of that control and thus you have to get a given row and then use find control.  Controls placed in a accordion are referenced just the same as if not using accordion control.  Thus this was zero to do with accordion and everything to do with nesting Controls in a table.

Thank you Albert, that makes total sense.
